# Not is showing numbers on columns from HighCharts

Tags: php, highcharts

I'm using highcharts for generate my reports, but, an little problem for showing the numbers at columns from highchart... In fact, two problems..

First problem:

[image: Problem with numbers in inside columns]

Second Problem:
[image]

This are problems is occurring of form random...

If you look at the first example has all the numbers at the top of the columns ...
And the second example has all the values inside the columns, however, with problem to display the values at the top of the column.

I would like to know if there is any possibility of forcing the Highcharts API to display this data at all times.

Example Chart:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({"chart":{"renderTo":"adwords_leads_all_94-3088","type":"column"},"title":{"text":"Leads AdWords - Convers\u00e3o - (Call Tracking | Chatbot | Formul\u00e1rio)"},"colors":["#68a9dc","#005a64","#003f23","#e4452b","#65c07f","#004b76","#6ecbd6","#ff7754","#83ccb0","#007b5a","#ec9631","#24a1ae","#e46a2b","#b6740c","#f79969","#1b964e","#fdc076","#147bb6","#ba0d00","#1d6c3f"],"xAxis":{"categories":["Mar\/2018","Abr\/2018","Mai\/2018","Jun\/2018","Jul\/2018"]},"yAxis":{"min":0,"title":{"text":"Quantidade"},"stackLabels":{"enabled":1,"style":{"fontWeight":"bold","fontSize":"16px","color":"#000"}}},"legend":{"align":"center","verticalAlign":"bottom","backgroundColor":(Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',"borderColor":"#CCC","borderWidth":1,"shadow":false},"tooltip":{"formatter":function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
            this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
            'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;}},"plotOptions":{"column":{"stacking":"normal","dataLabels":{"enabled":1,"color":(Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'}}},"series":[{"name":"Call Tracking","data":[0,99,454,297,409]},{"name":"Chatbot","data":[51,150,155,106,97]},{"name":"Formul\u00e1rio","data":[19,107,184,138,150]}]});
```

Comment: First one is a space issue. Second seems weird. In any case, example code would be nice.

Comment: In first case you can use plotOptions.column.dataLabels.allowOverlap = true (check API https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels.allowOverlap) or increase chart height to make more space for data labels. Please, send as code example or online demo with second issue as @HalvorStrand suggested.

Comment: Added code example in post main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Data labels are not rendered because there is too little space and by default dataLabels.allowOverlap is set to false. What you have to do is just increase chart height or set `dataLabels.allowOverlap = true`.

   Api reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels.allowOverlap

---

2. The second issue is very similiar to the first one. Now yAxis.stackLabels.allowOverlap is by default false so what you have to do is set it to true - `yAxis.stackLabels.allowOverlap = true`

   Api reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.allowOverlap

   Online demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/hbg0k78c/

Comment: Suggested approach for second issue is a workaround only. This is bug actually - stackLabel should render properly because it has enought space. It's gonna be reported as a bug. Thanks for catching this